# Expression Blend Path and TextBlock

Tags: path, expression-blend, textblock

I am creating a game board using Expression Blend with lots of irregular shapes. These shapes will have text blocks on them as labels. For a given shape and its text block, I want them to behave as one control. An example: on a blackjack table the "Insurance" betting area is a curved area with text that reads "Insurance Pays 2 to 1". What is the best way to make those to behave as one control? In this example, if I drag a chip on to either control - the text of the betting area - it should respond the same way. Would it be to make it into a user control? If not, what is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered over on Expression Forum for anyone else it helps. :)

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/4e640536-043b-4717-ab9a-73c309485af9

Comment: Yeah, I cross-posted. Thanks for linking it. :)